# Automating automated testsing

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

What I mean is automating test writing itself. Tester can perform some actions, they get recorded, and then can be used as a base for writing tests. I wasn't able to find any existing solutions, is it that hard to implement? Or did I miss something?

I mean it might be as simple as logging all touch/key events, and write tests using for example https://github.com/square/javawriter

UPD: I should've mentioned that I know of standard testing approaches:

- UiAutomator
- Roboelectric
- Espresso (android-test-kit)

But that wasn't what I meant. Writing tests by hand is a pain, and I wander if this process can be simplified.

UPD1: If anyone stumbles apon this question, [this](http://robotium.com/products/robotium-recorder) is what I meant. It's non-free, so I'd gladly check out free/opensource analog.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

Comment: Normally this means writing Junit tests. For UI-automated testing it will be more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Appium (iOS/Android) which is free and has a feature that lets you record actions, and run them through.  However this only works for UI functionality and any standard Unit tests will still need to be developed the standard way (manually).  As a note, Appium is new (~1 year old) so there may still be bugs (such as not running in iOS devices with Xcode 5.0.1 +)

[appium.io](http://appium.io/)

I feel it's worthwhile to mention that appium doesn't require any modifications/additions to your android/iOS projects like a few of the other solutions I have found.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

Please Calash https://github.com/calabash which is open and compatible with both iOS and Android.

Comment: I did't find anything about automating test writing. As I understood it, this library wraps Robotium and all tests are still has to be written manually with Ruby.

Comment: @RomanZhilich calabash-android has a set of predefinied steps so you don't need to write ruby code.